# Xcode Scene Editor measuring objects

Tags: macos, xcode

I have a 3d file opened on the xcode scene editor. I would like to 3d print the object in this file.

How can I check the size of parts the object so I know how big it will be when printed?

The size should be represented in units, and I will tell the printer whether these units are mm, cm or m, but I cannot for the life of me find how I can measure the features of the object to check this.

EDIT: The files are of type .obj if that matters.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What format is the 3D file saved to? Be sure to edit the main post using the edit button as comments are epemeral and limited which are visible after a couple get added.